iOS build Archive in Rider for Publishing to App Store Dotnet iOS
I am working on a Dotnet iOS app and recently we migrated to Dotnet 8 and from Visual studio Mac to Rider. But Rider doesn't show options to Archive for publish in Rider.
I try to do publish with Command dotnet publish -c Release -f net8.0-ios -r ios-arm64
But when I upload the build to Transporter, it gives quite a lot of errors. these errors I never got in Visual studio mac.
any help is appreciated.



Does your project open in the Xcode fro Rider? You may want to check it by right-clicking on the project name > Open in Xcode. Do you have a Developer profile set up there?
Also, here is the instruction on how to use iOS publishing from Rider:
SUPPORT-A-712 How to publish MAUI applications using Rider
